# How to use root browser to access databse

Tags: google-play-store, root-access

I'm sorry if I asking in the wrong places...

I just installed `root browser`. I can see all my data folder including the `database` created using `android studio`. But when I try to access the table, `root browser` will crashed. Do I need to download another software in order to access the `database` content ?

Thanks

Comment: Root browser is only an advanced file explorer, but it's not a database browser. You need another app to browses those databases (SQLite)

Comment: Hard to say without knowing *which* root-browser you've installed. You might need a [database browser](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_databases#group_973) for that if it's not integrated with your root browser. And of course your device must be rooted.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for your response. May I know which app I can use?

Comment: @Izzy  Ya, my device is rooted. Just have no idea how to access the `database` in `root browser`

Comment: Download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree&hl=en)

Comment: @Hoo you can follow Izzy's list, but I personally use [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin) after testing some of them.

Comment: @AndrewT. Do I still need to use root browser if I install the  SQLite Debugger?

Comment: No, since the app will ask for root access.

Comment: @Hoo you might need "root browser" (or any other root-capable [file explorer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman)) to explore the file system (including system areas). But you'll need a database browser to browse database contents. Andrew's [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin) should be a good choice; it's the best rated candidate in [my list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_databases#group_973) :)

Comment: Does the SQLite Debugger can see the image added from android studio? I see a <BLOB> in image column

Comment: Please don't add thanks (or the comments likes the recent ones with .... ) anywhere unless you've something constructive to add. They create noise on the site and are **useless** to others. To appreciate comments (if only they are useful), you can  upvote them.  Anyhow, have you tried any [SQLITE app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sqlite) so far?

Comment: @Firelord I'm using SQLite debugger